# How to calculate values while merging the different tables

Tags: sqlite

I have got the following 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER) 
INSERT INTO a VALUES 
(“2019-04-27”, 10), (“2019-04-29”,20), (“2019-04-30”,30), (“2019-05-01”,40); 

CREATE TABLE b (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER) 
INSERT INTO b VALUES 
(“2019-04-27”, 1), (“2019-04-27”,3), (“2019-04-27”,2), 
(“2019-04-28”,2), (“2019-04-28”,5), 
(“2019-04-29”,50), (“2019-04-29”,10), 
(“2019-04-30”,10), (“2019-04-30”,20), 
(“2019-05-01”,40), (“2019-05-01”,10), 
(“2019-05-02”,10), (“2019-05-02”,6); 

CREATE TABLE c (DATE TEXT) 
INSERT INTO c VALUES 
(“2019-05-01”);
```

Table c shows the holiday. There are conditions: 
1) in the output should be all dates from a and c, but date from the c (“2019-05-01”) should be NULL I need to merge in one table all 3 Tables

2) The final output is one column, where PPRICE from Table a is divided by PRICE from Table b (the values are the average value at a specific date (not hourly)).

3) However, if this division has NULL (in Table A are NULLS because not all the same dates as In table b and c), so the value in the table should be the same as in the previous day.

Here you can see intermediary steps after satisfying one of the conditions: 
The final output should be as in Condition 3 table

[image]

I am using SQLite and when I was trying to get the output, but writing code for 1 condition I have the right values, but too many columns using different kinds of JOINS and UNIONs (FULL OUTER JOIN does not work in SQLite). Could you help me with finding the correct code to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: The final output looks more like one column than one row.

Comment: Why tag 4 completely different RDBMS..? I have removed all the conflicting tags. Please take the time to tag properly; tagging multiple conflicting tags will only get your question ignored, it will not give it more exposure. *(If you are using SQL Server, which I doubt due to the `“”` characters to quote literal strings (I don't think any RDBMS uses those stylised double quote characters to be honest), why are you using a data type that has been deprecated for 15 years?)*

Comment: Sorry, One column should be. I changed it

Answer (score 0):

First with `UNION` get all the dates from tables `a` and `b`.
Then join to the returned dates the table `a`, a query from table `b` that returns the averages and the table `c` with `left` joins and calculate the *result* column.
Enclose this query inside a CTE and finally use the CTE to return the *final* results:

```
with cte as (
  select u.date, round (case when c.date is null then a.price / b.price end, 2) result 
  from (select date from a union select date from b) u 
  left join a on a.date = u.date
  left join(
    select date, avg(price) price 
    from b 
    group by date
  ) b on b.date = u.date
  left join c on c.date = a.date
)
select c.date,
  case 
    when c.result is null then
      (select result from cte where date = (
          select max(date) from cte
          where result is not null and date < c.date
        )
      )
    else c.result
  end result  
from cte c
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/31y95MJW43nHQWqSKPjJx6/1).
Results:

```
| date       | result |
| ---------- | ------ |
| 2019-04-27 | 5      |
| 2019-04-28 | 5      |
| 2019-04-29 | 0.67   |
| 2019-04-30 | 2      |
| 2019-05-01 | 2      |
| 2019-05-02 | 2      |
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. But what does the letter u mean in the 3rd row?

Comment: `u` is the alias of the subquery `(select date from a union select date from b)`. You can use it to refer to the subquery's columns.

Comment: Additionally,i.e. I got hourly data for Table b INSERT INTO b VALUES
("2019-04-27 13:00",1),("2019-04-27 20:00",3),("2019-04-27 23:44",2),
("2019-04-28 13:00",2),("2019-04-28 20:00",5), 
("2019-04-29 13:00",50),("2019-04-29 20:00",10),
("2019-04-30 13:00",10),("2019-04-30 20:00",20),
("2019-05-01 13:00",40),("2019-05-01 20:00",10),
("2019-05-02 13:00",10),("2019-05-02 20:00",6);
How the code changes? I tried when using left join:
select DATE(date), avg(price) price  from b 
    group by DATE(date)) b on DATE(b.date) = u.date - However, it is wrong.

Comment: This code works for the question and the sample data as you posted it.

Comment: with hourly data and my code I got error that "no such column b.date"

Comment: I figure out with substr function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Fine if your problem is solved. Now take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399